# Почему не появляется скролл в ячейке Grid при установленном размере "auto"?

Tags: c#, wpf

В `Grid` лежит три элемента, один из которых - это `DataGrid`. В `DataGrid` важно сохранить 32 отображаемые строки, если масштаб экрана маленький, то, соответственно, должен появляться скролл, но при установленном размере в `auto` у ячейки, в которой лежит `DataGrid` скролл не появляется. Если ставить ячейке размер `*`, в которой лежит `DataGrid`, то выравнивание последнего элемента "едет". Что можно сделать, чтобы скролл заработал?

`XAML`:

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="35*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Menu/>
    <DataGrid/>
    <StatusBar/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Вам надо установить auto для второй строки и * для первой (отчёт с нуля, конечно)

Comment: `Auto`, `*`, `Auto`

Comment: @aepot при таком подходе скролл работает, но тогда, что естественно, высота второй строки грида масштабируется от высоты элемента вложенного в неё. Суть в том, что в статусбаре у меня маленькая таблица, которая наполняется не сразу, соответственно, я ей не могу определить высоту и в итоге места хватает только для 1 строки.

Comment: В статус-баре должен быть статус-бар :) Можно еще например `ListView` вместо `DataGrid` использовать, особенно там, где нужно только показать данные, а не редактировать непосредственно в таблице.

Comment: @aepot Статус-баре отражает статус чего-либо, а если мне нужно показать много статусов одновременно? Добавил табличку для этой цели ) Попробую другие списочные элементы в таких же условиях.)

Comment: _а если мне нужно показать много статусов одновременно?_ [Вот здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61564124/12888024) я всплывашки писал. А вообще подойдет обычный `ItemsControl`, если юзеру не надо ничего выбирать из показанного. Предлагаю принять ответ, расположенный ниже, потому что он правильно отвечает на поставленный вопрос, просто вопрос сам по себе странный, и идти обдумывать смысл всего происходящего дальше.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавить в свойства `DataGrid`:

```cs
ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
```

Или поместить `DataGrid` в `ScrollViewer`.

```xml
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1">
    <DataGrid></DataGrid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Не появляется скролл(

Comment: Попробуйте поместить Datagrid в ScrollViewer. <ScrollViewer>
                    <DataGrid></DataGrid>
                </ScrollViewer>

Comment: Все равно не работает( Не понятно почему он не работает. В своих экспериментах максимум, что получилось - это установить размер ячейки 700*, в неё положить `DataGrid`, тогда скролл работает, но остальное выравнивается криво.